# Applying AR filter using React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, algorithm, augmented-reality, face-recognition

I want to make an app like snapchat in which we can apply different filters on our face after tapping on that filter. So I want to ask you guys that how can I integrate facial recognition algorithm's in my app and how can I use AR after that? It's my university final year project so I don't have much time.
Thanks

I've found different AR library's for AR but can't find a solution for facial recognition

Comment: `I don't have much time` maybe your choice of app is a little optimistic given you don’t know where to start/if it’s possible.

Comment: I know it's possible but actually I don't know how to integrate facial recognition